# Error correction model (to test for asymmetry) with stationary I(0) variables

Tags: time-series, cointegration, ecm

I have price series which are all stationary without taking any difference --> I(0).
Can I still perform an ECM model to test for asymmetry?

For example: 
Y= constant X; 
taking the residuals and separate this term in negative and positive ones (ECT+ and ECT-). 
Then:
D.Y=cons LD.X LD.Y ECT- ECT+
Is this correct for I(0) variables?

Comment: What do you mean by "asymmetry"? There is no need to try an ECM based hypothesis test on the cointegrating vector since a linear combination will be $I(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to. Your OLS will be consistent in this case. I don't see the valid reason for using the first differences in the ECM, unless they are I(1).

Comment: At present, this is really a comment, @user1492268, not an answer. Would you care to expand on it somewhat?

Comment: @ gung: Can you flag this as a comment?I am not sure what OP wanted to do?

Comment: I don't know enough about time-series to be sure about the question, but your answer may well be appropriate. I don't object to it being an answer--I just wonder if you might elaborate on your point a bit. I can also flag it if you'd prefer.

Comment: I added a sentence, but I guess I have answered the OP's question.

Comment: Given that the question is not well formulated, the answer is appropriate. If all variables are I(0), ECM is not needed. What kind of model should be used to test the asymmetry remains an open question, because the OP did not specify what precisely he(she) wants to test.